# Calling printf in own malloc function caused segmentation fault

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, printf, malloc

I'd like to "override" `malloc` in pure C with Linux GCC, for memory checking stuffs. Notice that `malloc()` is a weak symbol, it's OK to do that in pure C. i.e. Making a strong symbol of `malloc()`.

But I just found it crash if calling `printf()` inside my `malloc()` implementation, and if removing, it won't crash.

To reproduce:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void *__libc_malloc(size_t size);

static int cnt = 0;

void* malloc(size_t size) {
    printf("--- calling customized malloc\n");
    cnt += 1;
    if(cnt > 1) return NULL;

    return __libc_malloc(size);
}

static void leak_test1() {
    int* a = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
    a[0] = 3;
}

int main(){
    leak_test1();
    printf("cnt=%d\n", cnt);

    return 0;
}
```

Does it mean "calling printf is invalid in my own malloc()"? What's the deep reason? (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I suspect that `printf` calls `malloc` to allocate its buffer, in which case you would have created an infinite recursion.  You may need to bypass stdio for your output, or queue it up and print it out after `malloc` has returned.

Comment: If `printf` calls `malloc`, you created a recursion loop and blew up your stack.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, I also thought printf calls malloc, thus recursively calling...I put the variable `cnt`, but I should put the checking of `cnt` before `printf` is called.

Comment: Try replacing `printf` with `puts`-

Comment: What's `cnt` supposed to do? Count upwards until integer overflow is provoked? That's a bug.

Comment: @Lundin You're right. `cnt` is a bug in the pasted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that `printf` call `malloc` to allocate the buffer for `stdout`, so you get an infinite recursion.

You might be able to get around this issue by calling `fprintf(stderr, ...)` as `stderr` is unbuffered.

Comment: How can printf know about the malloc in the callee translation unit? In order to use malloc, it will have to include stdlib.h from inside the "stdio.c" standard lib, in which case the malloc there is the right one and not the "overloaded" one. The behavior you describe should only be possible if the whole of printf is a function-like macro, which I doubt.

Comment: I'd rather suspect this: malloc's function definition inside the library isn't named `malloc` but something else. Then in stdlib.h they have some trick with both the correct `malloc` function declaration, as well as some macro that overloads the function declaration with a call to the internal "something_else_malloc" (standard libraries are allowed to do this). But when the caller actually provides a function definition named `malloc`, that one is getting linked and the macro trick breaks. And after that, the infinite recursion you describe is possible.

Comment: Otherwise, if the stdlib malloc was named `malloc` too, the program shouldn't even link.

Comment: @Lundin: what you are describing is possible, but I doubt `malloc` is anything but a plain extern declaration with some attributes in `<stdlib.h>`. The precise semantics of weak symbols and dynamic symbol resolution is somewhat obscure to me, and probably alien to most programmers, even in the linux environment. I suggested a simple test to check if buffering is the issue (not a formal proof, but a strong indication). The OP did not comment on this suggestion, but accepted the answer, so my proposal must have solved the problem.